# How to make this (table) using divs and css

Tags: html, css, html-table

I need to know how to make this table using divs, css and right xhtml

```
    <table width="100%" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 130px">1</td>
            <td align="center">2</td>
            <td style="width: 130px">3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Why does this need to be in DIVs and not a table?

Comment: i was an old developer code templates using tables now time has changes as i see people using divs this is not data table i mean i need it for a template thanks. MAYBE I DID UNDERSTAND SOMETHING WRONG

Comment: See http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/6037/1253. Be sure to read the comments as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a good examples i found

[1] http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/satisharveti/introduction-to-page-layout-using-div-element/
[2] http://www.ezineasp.net/post/Div-3-Columns-Layout-using-CSS-Styles-Div-layout-1.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Like so?

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <span class="cell width130">1</span>
        <span class="cell">2</span>
        <span class="cell width130">3</span>
    </div>
</div>

.table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
}
.width130 {
    width: 130px;
}
```

Comment: It certainly makes more sense for non-tabular data if thats what you mean.

Comment: LeonidVinikov when we talk about CSS there is no such a thing as 'correct way'. This particular solution suggested by @jimjimmy1995 works for you and for me and is at the same time very elegant. To me the conclusion is simple: this IS the correct way.